# Is there a readily available liquid that's more dense than water and insoluble?

Tags: water, solubility

I am looking for any liquid that does not dissolve in water with higher density and does not react with water, one that is readily available.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate (at least in intent) of: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/641/liquid-which-neither-dissolves-in-water-nor-oil?rq=1

Comment: of course not ?

Comment: yes i too think that this question is not similar to the question you qouted

Comment: @user7063: Apologies, I leaped to conclusions about why you were asking for what you were.

Comment: The first solvents that come to my mind are  $\ce{CH2Cl2}$, $\ce{CHCl3}$, and $\ce{CCl4}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trichloroethylene is a common chemical solvent that has reasonably low toxicity, it has density ~1.5 g/ml. However, it slowly becomes restricted. Tetrachloroethylene also may be considered. Dichlormethan has reasonably low toxicity, but its BP is too low. I would not use the liquids mentioned without fume hood on regular basis. One-time exposure is probably OK, but repeating exposure may lead to cancer.  Chloroform may be considered, but I recommend to avoid it, it has accumulating liver toxicity. Tetrachloromethane should be avoided, it also has undesired toxicity.

Mercury MAY be considered, it is toxic if one is repeatedly exposed to vapours, but has very low vapour pressure and is reasonably cheap. But it has annoying tendency to produce small drops that are very hard to collect and move into smallest holes and accumulates in the system, so it clearly requires dedicated  workplace.

Liquids mentioned above are reasonably cheap, so if they are not restricted in your home country, you should be able to allow yourself one. Unfortunately, that's all ideas I got. Well, there are some more, but they either has unreasonable cost, or are too toxic. Bromine, for example, is toxic and, though not mixing with water, partially dissolves in it.

Comment: Wikipedia has a list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_liquid including some comments on toxicity. Not worth an answer since it was a simple search.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
The easiest way i observe is to use salt water and fresh water ,i would like to confirm if they are shake proof.Even if i shake the bottle the two liquids would not mix.

The list has some liquids which interest me.
I would like to know if they would not mix or react with water and if they are easily available for me to use.
For eg Clerici solution.

Thanks

Comment: Salt water and fresh water obviously mixes well. No offence, but if you plan to play with toxic chemical you need at least some basic chemical knowledge.

Comment: @user7063 I strongly encourage to drop the list from Wiki. It includes mostly rare and toxic chemicals and solutions of rare and toxic salts in water. The chemicals I listed are cheap and relatively safe, I worked with them and still alive and healthy.

Comment: @user7063 Actually, if you need a liquid that does not mix with water, it is much easier to use one that has lower density than water. Toluene, gasoline, oil,  hexane are well known examples that are relatively safe.

Comment: @Greg  thanks for your reply.
I am not a chemical expert neither a noob.
I have seen that sea water and fresh water do not easily mix in the sea. Thus i wanted to confirm its shakeproof.

Comment: @permeakra Thanks for the warning.
I have not handled any toxic chemcicals.
OF the list you mentioned could you temme which one is more appropriate the density values are not far away.
So i get the doubt they are not shakeproof .

Thanks

Comment: @user7063 From my list I recommend tri- or tetra-chloroethylene (NOT -ethane). The compounds do not mix with water but in presence of surfactants may produce emulsions with water. Well, don't mix them with surfactants. Check for solubility data when considering amount of liquid.